# Magento 2: Update shipping Methods on Custom field dropdown selection on Shipping form checkout page

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, checkout-page

i want to update shipping method on checkout page during custom field select option change in shipping form.

According to magento 2 default functionality shipping estimation reloads with zipcode and country field selction but i want this also reload with custom field.

[image]